# TCP client/server printing extra strings

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a program with a server and multiple clients can connect to that server through the predefined port nummber. By the way, this is TCP in C. I have the following `server` code below:

SERVER CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <pthread.h> 

void *connection_handler(void *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd , connfd , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr , cliaddr;
    listenfd = socket(PF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (listenfd == -1)
        puts("SOCKET CREATION ERROR!");
        puts("Socket created");

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
    listen(listenfd,2);;
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while( (connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, (socklen_t*)&c)) ){
            puts("Connection accepted");
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
            new_sock = malloc(1);
            *new_sock = connfd;

            if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
                perror("Thread Error Connection");
            return 1;
            }
            puts("Handler assigned");
        }

    if (connfd < 0)
    {
            perror("accept failed");
            return 1;
    }
        return 0;
}


void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char client_message[51]="";

    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 50, 0)) > 0 )
    {
            printf("%s",client_message);
        }

        if(read_size == 0)
        {
            puts("Client disconnected");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        free(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);
  char mesg[1024];

  if(argc!=2){ 
      printf("Usage: %s <ip_addr>\n",argv[0]);
      exit(1);
  }

  sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
  inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&servaddr.sin_addr);
  connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

  while(1){
    fgets(mesg,sizeof(mesg),stdin);
    sendto(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);
  }
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Socket created
Connection accepted
Handler assigned
Hello There!
What could be the problem?
I don't know?
the problem?
Hey!
't know?
the problem?
```

I typed in the following strings in the client terminal:

```
Hello There!
What could be the problem?
I don't know?
Hey!
```

The problem is when I typed the third string, the output is the third string with some parts of the second string still appearing. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: `new_sock = malloc(1); *new_sock = connfd;` : you must be new to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings are null terminated. You're not sending the zero byte that would terminate your string in your recieving buffer, so your printf will print out all characters it find until it reaches some zero byte. strlen returns length of string in number of characters, but without counting the zero byte at the end.

Try to change line in your client:

```
sendto(sockfd,mesg,strlen(mesg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);
```

Into:

```
sendto(sockfd,mesg,1+strlen(mesg),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);
```

Comment: It says that I can accept your answer in 3 minutes. Just wait for it, but great thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. TCP is stream oriented.
2. You can not expect that `write()` writes as much data as you told it to write, as well as you can not expect that `read()` reads as much data as you told it ro read.

This both put together means that to transfer N bytes via a socket the number of calls to `read()` does not necessarily needs to match the number of calls to `write()`.

And following this conclusion the only thing the reader could know is how much it read from the moment on it was created.

The only two synchronisation points between reader and writer are the creation and the shutdown of the connection. The period one can call a *session*.

So if one wants to transfer multiple blocks of data having different sizes unknown to the reader during **one** session one is in the need to establish additional synchronisation points **during** the session, that make the read detect that a full block had been received.

Doing so is implementing some sort of protocol.

There are endless possiblities how the protcol could look like. The detailed design of the protocol depends on the use cases which shall be covered by the application.

Assuming only text data shall be transfered a simple protocol could be to terminate each data block by a `\n`.

The writer loops around `write()` until all data is sent and finally sends a `\n`.

The reader loops around `read()` until a `\n` had been received.