# Why won't my code go into this loop? Socket Programming

Tags: c, sockets, if-statement

I am trying to create a simple socket connection.

**This is what my client is doing:**

```
strcpy(send_data, "Hello Server");
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);

strcpy(send_data, "Compression Method:  null(0)");                      
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);

strcpy(send_data, "end");                      
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
```

`send_data` is defined as `char send_data[1024]`

**Now here is my Server side :**

```
    int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);

    while(clntSock){

        int inMsgLen = recvfrom(clntSock, inMsg, 1024, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&clntAddr, (socklen_t*)&clntAddrLen);

        inMsg[inMsgLen] = '\0';

        if(strcmp(inMsg, "Hello Server") == 0){   // check if the client sent hello server

            printf("%s\n", inMsg);

        } else if(strcmp(inMsg, "end") == 0){  // check if client send end

            printf("\n WHY ISNT"T THIS EXECUTING\n"); // THIS IS NOT HAPPENING

        } else {

            printf("%s\n", inMsg);  //keep receiving and do nothing
        }
```

Now my server manages to do the first check ( ie check if client sent server hello ) and prints out this : `Hello Server`

and then it goes to the else statement and prints out : `Compression Method:  null(0)`

after that it keeps going into the else statement ... **it never executes the else if statement**

***Why is the else_if statement never getting executed?***

Comment: First of all you should start by checking errors. And that includes the `accept` call which theoretically could return a socket with the value `0` (meaning you won't enter the loop). What's worse is that you will enter the loop even if `accept` fails, as then `clnSock` will be `-1` which is also "true".

Comment: i am doing all error checks  - -i just didnt include them in this post as it would have been too long

Comment: This answer might help to understand how TCP sockets basically work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18845965/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the TCP layer you need to implement some kind of protocol. This means that your client should send some indicator, i.e. the fixed size length of the string that it is about to send, and then the actual string (for a simple protocoll).
In your server code you can not just receive and expect the string to arrive completely. It can be chopped up into several pieces, so what you can do is this:

```
 1. Client sends a fixed length header (for example. N chars which have the length of the following string)
 2. Since the server knows now that the the header has a fixed length, it should wait until this header has arrived.
 3. Parse the header to see how many data the client wants to send and then loop as long as a full message has not yet been delivered.
```

For more complex cases you might need a protocol that allows also to resynchronize in cases where the client sends erronous data, but that you must decide depending on how important that is for you. For a simple client/server a scheme like the above should do. I'm using the same approach.

Comment: Ok i finally get it .. so basically this is like packet fragmentation .. one packet sent from the client is not exactly one packet received

One follow up question how would i set up point 3 in your post ( parsing ) would you mind providing a sample code??

Comment: That depends on how you implement the header. IN my case, I send it as a string, using `sprintf` aequivalent. So the server receives a string like this `00010Test String`where the first 5 chars are the known fixed length header which I then parse with an `atoi` aequivalent into the number 10. Then the server loops until it received 10 charcters. If less characters are received it puts it in a accumulating waiting buffer, and if mor are received it cuts of the remainder, because this would be part of the next header/message sequence, putting it in a new buffer.

Comment: So for each header it create a seperate message, which is only returned to the caller, when the message is completed (which means, all bytes that the header tells me are received).

Comment: Just for completeness. When reading the header, the same rule applies, so you can not rely on the header being transmitted in a single call either. The server must simply receive whatever comes along and store it appropriatly, depending on it's state. The only difference is that the header has a well known size.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that one send equals one receive at the peer. It isn't so. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. If you want messages, you have to arrange them yourself, for example, lines, length-word prefix, type-length-value, XML, ...

Comment: Err, send lines, a length-word prefix, ... I did answer that.

Comment: i dont know what length-word prefix means ( i am very new at socket programming ). could you give me an example send and receive statement ?

Answer (score 0):

At the client side you are doing this:

`Send ("Hello Server");`

`Send("Compression Method:  null(0)");`

`Send("end");`

So, in your socket's stream you have this:

`Hello ServerCompression Method:  null(0)end`

At the time you issue the Recv(1024)  at the server, it may return from 1 single char to the whole of that string, meaning that you may receive any combination of that. That's why you need to tell the server how many characters you are sending in each send(). Also you may end each string with a special character like \n or \0 so that you may separate the strings at the server side. This is not very recomended since the string itself may have that special character in it.

If you want to send and receive individual packets consider using UDP instead of TCP. With UDP the server receives the packets as the client sends them. Before moving to UDP read and understand the pros&cons of UDP vs TCP [here](http://www.skullbox.net/tcpudp.php)

Comment: UDP is much more complicated to implement and not really suitable for sending complex data, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: thanks that helps .. here is a follow up:

if i do Send("12Hello SERVER"); where first two characters would represent # of characters in that particular send message, there is a possibility that those first two characters may get split up too ... 

so how do i compensate for that

Comment: You should be awaer that UPD can send data out of order. That's why it is not a really suitable protocol for a task like yours. TCP is a stream, so the data will be received in the correct order.

Comment: @sukhvir: What you may do is send a single byte first, then the string:

`strcpy(buffer, "Hello world");`

`byte len = strlen(buffer);`

`send(socket, (char *)&b, 1, 0);`

`send(socket, buffer, b, 0);`

At the server:
`recv(socket, (char *)&b, 1, 0);`

`recv(socket, buffer, b, 0);`